# QList of Qvectors clear

Tags: qt, qlist, qvector

In Qt documentation there is an example, where they use

```
foreach (QVector<QPointF> row, m_data)
    row.clear();
m_data.clear();
```

to clear `<QList<QVector<QPointF> > m_data;`

Is it necessary to use such a construction or just `m_data.clear();` is enoungh?

Qt example [page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-datasource-cpp.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only it is useless, but is can be "harmful".

It is useless because `QList<T>::clear()` will destroy every T it owns effectively calling `~T()`. In your case that means that you end up calling `~QVector<QPointF>()` for every vector in the QList. And then `~QVector<QPointF>()` will call `~QPointF()` for every point.

It can be harmful performance wise because QList and QVector use Copy-on-Write. That means that when you copy a list you do not copy the internal data, but a copy will happen as soon as you perform an action that will modify one of the list.

So if `m_data` shares its internal data with another QList, changing any of its element (eg. by calling `QVector::clear()` on one of them) will trigger a hard copy of the QList internal data. And this copy is completely useless as you discard it just after by calling `m_data.clear()`.

---

Also worth noting that:

```
foreach (QVector<QPointF> row, m_data)
    row.clear();
```

Does not change `m_data`. You clear `row` which is a local variable. And even if you en up writing:

```
foreach (QVector<QPointF> &row, m_data)
        row.clear();
```

It will have no effect as, quoting Qt doc:

> Since foreach creates a copy of the container, using a non-const
>   reference for the variable does not allow you to modify the original
>   container. It only affects the copy, which is probably not what you
>   want.